# BASH printf function to print variable containing an asterisk symbol

Tags: bash, printf

I'm trying to get the printf function to print out a line of variables with stored values, one of which can possibly contain an asterisk symbol. Reasoning for using printf is so that I can follow the format style already within the limits.conf file, having each variable fixed in a designated amount of space. It works fine with anything other than "*".

```
printf "#"'%-15s %-7s %-15s %-8s\n' $domain $type $item $value >> ~/etc/security/limits.conf
```

lets say for instance:
    domain=*
    type=hard
    item=core
    value=100

When doing this, I strangely get a listing of all my directories in the limits.conf file, even though the value of domain is "*" Not sure at all for a way around this. Hope someone can help! Thanks in advance!

An example of how the entry looks:

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

```
printf "#"'%-15s %-7s %-15s %-8s\n' "$domain" "$type" "$item" "$value" >> ~/etc/security/limits.conf
```

That should protect the * from filename expansion - which is what you are seeing. It also prevents other problems.